# Typescript object properties depending on type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define an event handler that can be used for different components that mostly share event.target structure:

```
import { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material'

const handleValueChange = ({ target }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | SelectChangeEvent) => {
  const { name, value, type, checked } = target

  setState({
    [name]: type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value
  })
}
```

The problem that I have is that `type` and `checked` do not exist on `SelectChangeEvent` type:

```
Property 'checked' does not exist on type '(EventTarget & { value: string; name: string; }) | (EventTarget & HTMLInputElement)'.
```

I don't really want to duplicate the code and create another handler just because of type difference. I can ensure in the code that when I call this handler it is actually going to have the needed properties, but how do I tell that to Typescript?

If my approach is incorrect, how should I refactor this to make it work without duplication (if possible)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do it with a type assertion, like this:

```typescript
const handleValueChange = ({ currentTarget }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | SelectChangeEvent) => {
    const { name, type, value, checked } = currentTarget as HTMLInputElement;
    setState({
        [name]: type === "input" ? checked : value
    });
};
```

...it's best to avoid type assertions where possible. ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQBYEMB2BzApgUQDddN4BfOAMyghDgCIpd0BjGegbgChRJZE4AZVwAbXGzRY8REuSo069AAIgArsAD0IdDFxRg6EZy5cAJuJHomcFhEwBnePdwxBMHbgBccABSOP3gBK4tCmADyO+jgANHBYAJ4AfACUcAC8iXCEEMCm3Fy2DvAYmKZiAGqGqriSOLjpvkgsqlBMpAAqVnjk3rXSxKRhABLtALIAMgCSmGCqMPhiILKZAD5CouIwfQQDMKkZiFxwxzZ2jgKY6EuxMPFguLGEVQ82qOIA1rimcBRpNi1tGCdKDdOL2OAjCbTWbzRaybgnODOVzuXQ+BBHREnADalyWAF1vLd7uk0n96MAZnN6HAAPyvD5fODeJ4iaqY45kZLcMjcIA).) In the above, for instance, you **know** you're getting `undefined` for `type` when it's used with a `select` element. It still works, because `type` won't be `"input"` when it's a `select` element, so you'll end up using `value` instead of `checked`, but it's best avoided in all but very limited situations. The above may well be limited enough for many people, given the types on the function.

Instead, to be more rigorous, you can narrow the type of `currentTarget` (usually a better choice than `target`) with a type guard or two so that the type information is guaranteed to match the runtime reality.

We can start with an `instanceof` check:

```typescript
const handleValueChange = ({ currentTarget }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | SelectChangeEvent) => {
    let value: string | boolean;
    if (currentTarget instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
        value = currentTarget.checked;
    } else {
        value = currentTarget.value; // <== But we still have errors here
    }
    const { name } = currentTarget;  // <== and one here
    setState({
        [name]: value
    });
};
```

The errors are because `currentTarget` may be `null` and, in the `else` branch, is just of type `EventTarget`.

We can solve that with a second `instanceof` check and a `throw`:

```typescript
const handleValueChange = ({ currentTarget }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | SelectChangeEvent) => {
    let value: string | boolean;
    if (currentTarget instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
        value = currentTarget.checked;
    } else if (currentTarget instanceof HTMLSelectElement) {
        value = currentTarget.value;
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Expected an HTMLInputElement or HTMLSelectElement`);
    }
    const { name } = currentTarget;
    setState({
        [name]: value
    });
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thanks a lot for example, but this seems even uglier than an option to have 2 separate handlers :D damn TS! I guess I will either disable the error with inline comment or have to do those 2 separate handlers :(

Comment: @VytautasButkus - It's the cost of rigorous type safety. But if you like, again, you *can* do it with a type assertion. I've added an example of that.

Comment: Actually, I managed to make it a bit shorter, I just needed this check: `if (target instanceof HTMLInputElement) { value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : value }`